# Backbone bind event fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to build a switching view with backbone js and found out my bind event fired multiple times, when I switching view for few times.

Below is the code for better illustration:

html

```
<div id='container'>
    halo world
</div>

<button id='but1'>red view</button>
<button id='but2'>blue view</button>
```

css

```
#red_view{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:red;        
}
#blue_view{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:blue;        
}
.button,.button2{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

​
javascript

```
RedView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",
    events:{"click .button":"clickme"},
    clickme:function(){
        alert('redview');                        
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.html("<div id='red_view'><div class='button'>Click Me</div></div>");            
    }
});

BlueView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",
    events:{"click .button2":"clickme2"},
    clickme2:function(){
        alert('blueview');                        
    },    
    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.html("<div id='blue_view'><div class='button2'>Click Me</div></div>");            
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    //var router = new SystemRouter();

    $('#but1').click(function(){
       var view = new RedView();
    });
    $('#but2').click(function(){
       var view = new BlueView();
    });    
});
```

If you click the red view for 3 times, and press 'click me'. It will pops up alert for 3 times as well. I suspect there's need to unbind the event somewhere, but couldn't find proper way to do it. Best to provide some references of doing this correctly.

​Here's the link to jsfiddle demo. http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/DwRRk/31/

Comment: You are not cleaning your views up, leaving you with ghost views. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every time you click the `red view` or `blue view` -buttons you create a *new Red or Blue View each and every time*. You bind their events hash to respond to click DOM events originating from buttons with classes `button` and `button2`.

1. Press 'red view' 3 times -> 3 instances of RedView created
2. Click button with class 'button' -> DOM event
3. 3 instances of RedView listening to said DOM event -> 3 alerts

This is because you don't clean the views before creating a new one effectively leaving you with ghost views that respond to events even though they can't be seen. [(More info on the events hash)](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) You can clean the events from you views with something like this.

```
cleanup: function() {
  this.undelegateEvents();
  $(this.el).clear();
}
```

Here is your fiddle with working cleanup of views http://jsfiddle.net/DwRRk/34/

Also a hint for good practice: you should use something like a render method to attach stuff to your DOM, use the initialize to just initialize the needed values for your view.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new view everytime the buttons are clicked, without destroying the previous one. Try using a single view likes this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DwRRk/32/

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#container",
    model: SomeModel,
    events: {
        "click .button": "clickme"
    },
    clickme: function() {
        alert(this.model.get("color"));
    },
    colorChanged: function() {
        this.$el.html("<div id='" + this.model.get("color") + "_view'><div class='button'>Click Me</div></div>");
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll( this, "colorChanged" );
        this.model.on("change:color", this.colorChanged );
        this.model.on("reset", this.colorChanged );
    }
});



$(document).ready(function() {
    //var router = new SystemRouter();
    var model = new SomeModel({color: "red"}),
        view = new SomeView({model: model})


    $('#but1').click(function() {
        model.set("color", "red");
    });
    $('#but2').click(function() {
        model.set("color", "blue");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you. That provide me new idea of how to implement it differently, but for my case I have a 2 very different view, which I will instantiate it base on routing. So, I am curious on how to implement that.

Comment: @TonyMocha can you just change hidden/shown status of them depening on what's routed?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of deleting ghost views(what i'm using)

```
disposeView: function(view){
   Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
      this.unbind();
      this.undelegateEvents();
   };

   /* --Destroy current view */
   if(this.currentView !== undefined) {
      this.currentView.close();
   }

   /* --Create new view */
   this.currentView = view;
   this.currentView.delegateEvents();

   return this.currentView;
}

disposeView(new view());
```

Be sure to always return "this" in your view or else this won't work.

Comment: This is super slick. This is the simplest solution that works. I have faced a lot of troubles with Backbone Zombie views till this came to rescue. Thank you!